# Sql Injection em Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-injection, vulnerabilidade

É possível realizar injeção de *SQL* em *Stored Procedures*, especialmente ao chamar uma *Procedure* pelo *PDO* do PHP?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE
  procedureTeste( string VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome = string;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Seria possível realizar *SQL Injection* em uma *Procedure* utilizando o `bindParam` do *PDO*?

```
$PDO = $this->PDO->prepare('call procedureTeste(:nomeProd)');
$PDO->bindParam(':nomeProd', $nome, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$PDO->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> É possível realizar injeção de sql em stored procedures?

Depende da forma como você cria essas *procedures*, de qualquer forma não é seguro deixar o usuário informar qualquer valor. Isso porque o usuário pode digitar um texto muito longo e acabar tendo acesso a mensagens de erro (caso estejam habilitadas e não filtradas). Isso irá deixar exposto sua estrutura de dados e como você trabalha com ele.

E obviamente, ele saberá que você não trata os dados de entrada e saída.

**Estrutura de tabelas:**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user        | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_access | timestamp    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Stored Procedures vunerável:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS login;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE login( u VARCHAR(255), p VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user` = '", u, "' AND `password` = '", p,"'");

    SELECT @query;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Veja que se eu executar a *query* abaixo, o MySQL irá retornar todos os registros.

```
CALL login("' OR '1' = '1", "' OR '1' = '1");
```

**Stored Procedures <strike>invunerável</strike> mais segura:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS login2;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE login2( u VARCHAR(255), p VARCHAR(255) )
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM users WHERE `user` = u AND `password` = p;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Veja que se eu executar a *query* abaixo, o MySQL **não** irá retornar os registros.

```
CALL login2("' OR '1' = '1", "' OR '1' = '1");
```

Isso ocorre, pois da segunda forma as *Stored Procedures* são pré compilados. Em outras palavras, o banco de dados cria esse software interno antes de usá-lo. Neste caso, somente o código de programa é interpretado sem qualquer influência de parâmetros.

---

> Seria possível realizar *SQL Injection* em uma *procedure* com `bindParam` do PDO?

A vantagem é que o valor do parâmetro (com `bindParam`) nunca é interpolado na sequência da consulta.

Então sim, os parâmetros de consulta ajudam você a evitar essa vulnerabilidade de segurança. Porém, é necessário ter consciência e não fazer de qualquer jeito no código MySQL.

---

<sup>Referências:</sup>
<sup>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314521/how-safe-are-pdo-prepared-statements</sup>
<sup>https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68701/how-does-stored-procedure-prevents-sql-injection</sup>
<sup>https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection/</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, essa duvida estava me matando, gostaria de implementar procedures no sistema que estou fazendo, e seu exemplo me ajudou muito :)